# Firebase (angular) deploy

Tags: angular, firebase, deployment, google-cloud-functions

Error: Your project  must be on the Blaze (pay-as-you-go) plan to complete this command. Required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com can't be enabled until the upgrade is complete. To upgrade, visit the following URL:

Is there any version that works ?

I tried to deploy my project to firebase so I can be able to use cloud functions and it gives me an error because of my free plan :D

Comment: You can't avoid being on a paid plan in order to deploy functions.

Answer (score 1):

Some firebase options are blocked for a free plan. However, switching to the pay-as-you-go plan does not mean you will need to pay something. Normally, pay-as-you-go has a free threshold.
So, explore conditions for the Blaze and check if you will use more than allowed below the threshold.

Comment: With the Blaze plan, you still get the same limits & quotas as the Spark (free) plan before any sort of additional billing occurs.  See the "No-cost usage from Spark plan included*" note on this page: https://firebase.google.com/pricing